# phing untar task ignores .gitignore files

Tags: php, build, phing

I have a `.tar.gz` file that I want to extract with the `untar` task of `phing`. In the [phing docu](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/UntarTask.html) there is this commans listed:

```
<untar file="testtar.tar.gz" todir="dest">
  <fileset dir=".">
    <include name="*.tar.gz"/>
    <include name="*.tar"/>
  </fileset>
</untar>
```

But the resulting folder is not the same then it is in the compressed file.
The untar command compleatly ignores the `.gitignore` files. But these are also files I want to extract. I want to extract **all** files that are contained in the compressed file.

Am I missing a parameter or something?
(The `forceExtract` parameter does nothing.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I checked the docs. I have never used phing, so I can not help you in this way. All I can tell you, that files with a dot in the beginning like .gitignore are so called "hidden" files in unix/linux file systems. If you search around for "phing untar hidden files" you might end up finding something.

Comment: I know what hidden files are. The interesting thing is, that files like `.htaccess` can be extracted perfectly. only the special file `.gitignore` will not be extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs it has to be like that:

```
<untar file="testtar.tar.gz" todir="dest">
  <fileset dir="." defaultexcludes="false">
    <include name="*.tar.gz"/>
    <include name="*.tar"/>
  </fileset>
</untar>
```

Docs: https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/FileSet.html at D.3

Comment: ok, my mistake. I already tested the `defaultexcludes=false` in my untar task, but forgot it in my tar task. Thanks a lot :)